# What is difference between calling isdigit(c) and isdigit(c&0xFF). Masking the isdigit "&0xFF"

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, mask

The function isdigit can be called with a character but if we send an and bit "&" with the 255 decimal number  why we do that. I have found this from a sample example in c

```
      const char *value =1234567890abcdefghijklm";
     for(i=0; value[i]; i++)  {
      int r1 = isdigit(value[i]);
      int r2 = isdigit(value[i]&0xFF);
      printf("%d %d\n", r1,r2);
```

if I output the above I can not see the difference between r1 and r2

```
2048 2048
2048 2048
2048 2048
2048 2048
2048 2048
2048 2048
2048 2048
2048 2048
2048 2048
2048 2048
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
```

0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0

why masking the value by 255 (1byte)?

Comment: because `0xFF` is `11111111`, so `c & 0xFF == c` for any `c`

Comment: @EmanuelP who said that? `c` can be signed and `c && 0xFF` will be different from C. And `c` can have more than 8 bits and masking out the out 8 bits also changes the value. Who said that `char` is an 8-bit type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument to `isdigit` is of type `int`, and must be either equal to `EOF` (typically -1) or in the representable range of `unsigned char`.

If plain `char` is signed, then it can hold negative values, and passing a negative value other than `EOF` to `isdigit` has undefined behavior. That means that passing an element of a string to `isdigit` is unsafe.

The usual way to avoid this problem is to convert the argument to `unsigned char`:

```
int r2 = isdigit((unsigned char)value[i]);
```

and in fact I recommend doing it that way.

Doing a bitwise and with `0xff` probably has the same effect, though there may be some subtle differences involving integer promotions and applying bitwise operations to signed types (which I'm too lazy to figure out).

The purpose of doing a bitwise and with `0xff` is to avoid undefined behavior when calling `isdigit`. But converting to `unsigned char` is a bit cleaner.

Comment: bitwise AND on signed values is defined but you may run into trap on negative zero, I was more curious than lazy :-)

Comment: @AllanWind IIRC, character types cannot have a trap value: "If such a representation is produced by a side effect that modifies all or any part of the object by an lvalue expression that does not have character type, the behavior is undefined. Such a representation is called a trap representation." § 6.2.6.1 5.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `value[i]` is a `const char`, and it's implementation defined if char is signed or unsigned, but `isdigit(c)` "checks whether c, which must have the value of an unsigned char or EOF, falls into  a  certain character  class  according to the specified locale."  Without the cast the behavior is undefined if your system happens to use a `signed char`.

The type of `value[i] & 0xFF` is an `int` but as you restrict it to 0xFF there is no risk of it being negative.  It is well defined but perhaps a little confusing.

`isdigit()` returns a nonzero value on success so the actual value you print out doesn't carry any meaning.

Comment: `isdigit()` takes and `int` argument, not `unsigned char`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Revised.  Let me know if I missing anything.

Comment: You still say that "`isdigit()` technically requires a `(unsigned char)`", which is at best misleading. If you mean it requires a cast to `unsigned char`, that's nearly true. If you mean it requires an argument of type `unsigned char`, it isn't. The parameter is of type `int`, and `isdigit(EOF)` (where `EOF` is a negative `int` value) is explicitly permitted. Without a cast the behavior is well defined *if* the argument happens to be non-negative (which it will be for any character within the basic character set).

Comment: I replaced the section with the man page quote.

Comment: You cut off the quote too soon; it "checks whether c, ..." *what*? You don't mention that the parameter type is `int`. The behavior is well defined if the value of `c` is non-negative.

Comment: @KeithThompson Updated as requested.  I was speaking type of the argument not the behavior of the function.

Answer (score 1):

To reinforce the above two answers from Keith and Allan, I have found the following link
[isdigit function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit)

It says

> The behavior is undefined if the value of ch is not representable as
> unsigned char and is not equal to EOF.

Answer (score 1):

As well answered by others that `is...(x)` functions are defined for `EOF` and `unsigned char` values.

How about an example when does `&0xFF` make a difference?

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void is_test(const char *s) {
  puts(s);
  for (int i = SCHAR_MIN; i <= SCHAR_MAX; i++) {
    bool signed_test = isalpha(i);  // UB risk here.
    bool unsigned_test = isalpha(i & UCHAR_MAX);
    if (signed_test != unsigned_test) {
      printf("%3d %d, %3d %d\n", i, signed_test, i & UCHAR_MAX, unsigned_test);
    }
  }
  puts("");
}

int main() {
  printf("EOF %d\n", EOF); 
  is_test("Initial state");
  char *loc = "no_NO.ISO-8859-1";
  char *retval = setlocale(LC_ALL, loc);
  if (retval) {
    is_test(loc);
  }
}
```

Output.  Character 255 in [IEC_8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) is the *character* `ÿ` and -1 is non-character `EOF`.

```
EOF -1
Initial state

no_NO.ISO-8859-1
 -1 0, 255 1
```

--

Only for the pedantic: How to work with characters outside the 0-127 range?

```
isdigit(value[i] & 0xFF);          // OP
isdigit(value[i] & UCHAR_MAX);     // Better - non-magic number- handle non-8-bit char
isdigit((unsigned char) value[i]); // Same as above
```

Yet the best, until C23 comes out, is

```
isdigit(((unsigned char*) value)[i]);
```

This follows C's <string.h>

> For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type `unsigned char` (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a different value).

These differ when `char` uses non- 2's complement encoding and `value [i]` is negative (including -0).

```
// ones' complement example
isdigit( (unsigned char ) value [i]);  // e.g. -0 --> 0
isdigit(((unsigned char*) value)[i]);  // e.g. -0 --> 255
```

Comment: C23 (almost certainly) won't change this. From the [N3054 draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3054.pdf): "The header `<ctype.h>` declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping characters.  In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @KeithThompson The "best" I refer to, until C23 comes out,  is `isdigit(((unsigned char*) value)[i]);`, after that `isdigit(value[i] & UCHAR_MAX);` and `isdigit((unsigned char) value[i]);` are as good.  Before C23 they may differ.  C23 certainly will drop non- 2's complement encoding - that is what the last section is about.  Not about `ctype.h` acceptable values, but passing the correct `unsigned char` value.